# Overriding the clean() function in BaseInlineFormSet

Tags: python, django, validation

I am trying to override the clean() function in the BaseInlineFormSet to check for some value first ... if it exceeds the limit it raise a `ValidationError`

but what happens is when the user validate the condition it stops at the `raise` part and nothing happens. The form isn't saved and the error is not raised... any explanation?

```
class BaseDetailFormSet(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        super(BaseDetailFormSet, self).clean()
        if any(self.errors):
            return

        for form in self.forms:
            product = form.cleaned_data['product']
            if form.cleaned_data['quantity_sold'] > product.quantity_in_stock:
                raise forms.ValidationError('not enough products') #code stops here
```

the views.py:

```
def create_invoice(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        invoice_form = InvoiceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        detail_formset = DetailFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if invoice_form.is_valid() and detail_formset.is_valid():
            amount = 0
            invoice = invoice_form.save()

            for form in detail_formset:
                detail = form.save(commit=False)
                detail.invoice = invoice
                product = Products.objects.get(id=detail.product_id)
                detail.product_price = product.unit_price
                detail.product_description = product.description
                amount += Decimal(detail.product_price * detail.quantity_sold) *\
                          (1 - (product.discount / 100))
                form.save()

                product.quantity_in_stock -= detail.quantity_sold
                product.save()

            amount *= Decimal((1 - (invoice.discount / 100)))
            invoice.amount = amount
            invoice.remaining = amount
            invoice_form.save()

            # updating Customer Balance And Invoice Remaining
            customer = Customer.objects.get(id=invoice.customer_id)
            current_invoice = Invoices.objects.get(id=invoice.id)
            customer.balance -= current_invoice.amount
            customer.save()


    else:
        invoice_form = InvoiceForm()
        detail_formset = DetailFormset()

    return render(request, 'inventory/new_invoice.html',
                  {'invoice_form': invoice_form,
                   'detail_form': detail_formset})
```

this pat in html template:

```
<tr class="formset_row">
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        <td>
                            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                    {{ hidden }}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
                            {{ field }}
                        </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
```

note: i am sure that it enters the `if` part so i am sure it stops at the raise line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'it stops at the raise part and nothing happens'. It sounds like you are not displaying the errors correctly in your template.

If you raise `ValidationError` inside the base formset's `clean` method, you will be able to access the errors with `formset.non_form_errors()` in your view, or `{{ formset.non_form_errors }}` in your template.

In your case, you are passing the formset to the context as `detail_form` (not a good name -- it's a formset not a form).

```
return render(request, 'inventory/new_invoice.html',
              {'invoice_form': invoice_form,
               'detail_form': detail_formset})
```

Therefore you access the non form errors with `{{ detail_form..non_form_errors }}`.

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) for more info.

Comment: i mean the the error is not raised and the form isn't saved .. just the page reloads with the same data  
i used the `{{ form.non_form_errors }}` in the forms and still nothing happen

Comment: Oops, that should be `{{ formset.non_form_errors }}`.

Comment: I edited the post and added the html is use in the template .. check it and see if i am doing anything wrong

Comment: You are including `{{ formset.non_form_errors }}` inside the loop -- you only need to include it once. You haven't shown the rest of the template or the view, so I can't tell whether that will work or not. To debug the problem, simplify your template to the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) `<form method="post" action=""><table>{{ formset }}</table></form>`. That way you can tell whether the problem is in your template or the view/formset class.

Comment: I simplified the template as u said .. still no error message raised

Comment: That suggests the problem might be in your view, which you haven't shown.

Comment: I added the views in the post.. I know this toke long but can u review it and see what is worng

Comment: Check `detail_formset.errors` and `invoice_form.errors` in your view. You have `'detail_form': detail_formset` in your template context, therefore it should be `{{ detail_form.non_form_errors }}` in your template. As an aside, `detail_form` isn't a good name -- it's a formset not a form.

Comment: I have just seen this. I tried ` {{ detail_form.non_form_errors }}` and it worked fine for me .. thanks any way my friend

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to catch the exception when overriding the clean method in BaseDetailFormSet (and append to self._non_form_errors)